# Attaching sql database to asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I want to attach the sql server database to my asp.net web application. How can i do it ?

Please help me

Thank you in anticipation

Comment: is this a local sqlexpress instance, is it a remote SQL server?  www.connectionstrings.com

Comment: it is a local sql server database i created on my computer using Sql Server Management Studio express 2005. I want to attach it to my web application project and when i try to point to the location of my database it says I don't have necessary permissions. What should I do? Please help me. Thank you in anticipation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click you AppData folder and select add|new item then select SQL Database

You can then use the Visual Studio database tools to develop the database.

Remeber, when you publish your site, ensure you have selected to include the contents of the AppData folder in your publish script

Comment: when i try to point the already existing mdf database from the window that pops up by pointing add existing item by right clicking appfolder, it says that I don't have necessary permissions.

Comment: This may depend on the kind of database you are looking at. SQL Server can create either a "file" database or a "server" database. You will only be able to add a "file" database and then you should have permissions (if you created it and you are the database owner). In all honesty it is simpler to add a new database in Visual Studio (it will then be a "file" type database) and the script across your structure/data